# How can I customize the width of a marker popup info window in Android Maps V2

Tags: android, maps, google-maps-markers, android-maps-v2

I am using Android Maps V2 and have a set of markers that display custom content in the popup info windows, on tap. I used a custom implementation of the InfoWindowAdapter to feed the popup dynamic content in a custom layout. By default though, the width of the popup will always take over the entire width of the map layout. Is there a way to customize it, add some lateral padding, control the width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override getInfoWindow to return a custom view:

```
@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
}
```

You can inflate a custom view resource (xml) in your InfoWindowAdapter constructor (for instance):

```
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
```

If you installed the google play services sdk there is a sample application for maps in samples/maps (where the example code is coming from)

Comment: Why is this the accepted solution? I don't specifying Xdp as layout_width is a proper solution. I am looking for something like view.setWidth(80% of screenwidth). Does anyone know such property?

Comment: This does not handle setting the width.